# Reminder of equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, diophantine-equations

I have a simple(maybe too simple) question - how to find the reminder of equation? For example:

$(85^{74}+17^{95})^{15} \equiv    \ ? \ (mod\ 13)$

I know that it is something simple, but I couldn't get it :( .

I will be very helpful if someone got some time and explain it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do this, but does it help that $85=17*5$?

Comment: no, but thanks for the reply :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split it into pieces.

For example, working modulo $13$, note that $85\equiv 7$. Also $17\equiv 4$. So we are now looking at $$(7^{74}+4^{95})^{15}$$

Next we note that if $(n,13)=1$ Fermat tells us that $n^{12}\equiv  1$, so we can reduce the exponents by arbitrary multiples of $12$. This gives us $$(7^2+4^{-1})^3$$

Now we note that $4\cdot 10=40\equiv 1$ so that $4^{-1}$ can be replaced by $10$ to give $$59^3\equiv 7^3$$

Then it is by hand. $7^3=343$ is a fact I know. $343=26\cdot 13+5$

Comment: Or $49\equiv 10$ so $49\cdot 7\equiv 70 \equiv 5$

Answer (score 0):

Doing arithmetic modulo $\;13\;$ all the way:

$$\left(85^{74}+17^{95}\right)^{15}=\left(7^{74}+4^{95}\right)^{15}$$

But

$$7^2=10=-3\;,\;\;7^4=(-3)^2=9\;,\;\;7^5=9\cdot7=11=-2\;,\;\;7^6=7\cdot(-2)=-1\implies$$

$$7^{74}=\left(7^6\right)^{12}\cdot7^2=10$$

Likewise

$$4^3=64=-1\implies 4^{95}=\left(4^3\right)^{31}\cdot4^2=-16=10$$

Thus

$$\left(7^{74}+4^{95}\right)^{15}=7^{15}=7^{13}\cdot7^2\stackrel{\text{Fermat's Little Th.}}=7\cdot10=5$$

Comment: ? couldn't get it, sorry :( ...could you explain in more details?

Comment: What did you try? Do you know modular arithmetic, Fermat's Little Theorem and etc.?

Comment: I haven't try anything; I don't know from where to start...

Comment: @MathError, but you **must** know some modular arithmetic, right? Otherwise this exercise is not for you...

Comment: @DonAntonio I saw the correction and deleted the comment.